# Is Salesforce classed as a consumer of Platform events?

Tags: platform-event, cometd

As the title suggests, I would like to know if Salesforce is classed as a CometD subscriber to Platform events? In the documentation it mentions there is 25K message limit divided by subscribers, is Salesforce counted towards this?

If I were to create a process builder to trigger changes off the back of a platform event is this counted? or even an apex trigger?

Comment: I would think it would only be 3rd party API subscribers that would be counted (not SF itself like triggers)

Comment: Is there any documentation which verifies this somewhere? Or someone that has done this that can verify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Limits doc you are referring to is here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm)

SFDC is NOT a CometD subscriber for

- Events published to Salesforce via the API
- Events published to Salesforce from within the same org

In my org, for example, I've easily received 100,000 events per hour from a third party API client (Boomi)

I can agree that the doc can be a bit confusing here, but if you [look at this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe.htm), you can see there are many types of subscribers, only one of which is CometD and it is associated with "external" subscribers.

There is also a long set of discussions about the limits in the [Platform Events Success Group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000004gjg)